# Why the details of a registration appears incorrectly if the same user does more than 1 registration in same conference?

Tags: php, laravel

If the user select quantity "1" for the registration type "general" and 1 for "plus" and click "Next" there is a registration form that will ask for the name and surname of both participants being registered. If the user fill the form like:

```
Name of participant 1:  Jake
Surname of participant1: W

Name of participant 2:  John 
Surname of participant 2: K
```

And click in "Register" the participant becomes registered in the conference.

Then I have a page with a list of users that did a registration in a confernece like:

```
@foreach($conference->registrations as $registration)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$registration->customer->name}} {{$registration->customer->surname}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{route('conferences.registrationInfo', ['regID'=> $registration->id])}}"
               class="btn">Download registration details
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Each list item has a link "Download registration details" when this button is clicked it should download a pdf with a summary of that specific registration.

If there is only 1 registration in the conference, with the details above (2 participants, Jake W registered in the registration type general and John K registered in the registration type plus), when the user click in the "Download registration details" is downloaded a pdf that shows 2 lists, each list has the details of each participant registered, so the pdf shows:

```
List 1:
Conference name: conference 1
Participant: Jake W
Registration type: general

List 2:
Conference name: conference 1
Participant: John K
Registration type: plus
```

So its working fine, shows the correct results.

**Issue:** However if the user does anothere registration in the same conference. For example the user select quantity "1" for the registration type "general" and introduce in the registration form like:

```
Name of participant 1:  Jake
Surname of participant1: W
```

And click in "Register". Then, the same "Download registration details" link for the same registration, clicked before, downloads a pdf that instead of show the same two lists above, shows 3 lists repeating the list 1 twice, like:

```
List 1:
Conference name: conference 1
Participant: Jake W
Registration type: general

List 2:
Conference name: conference 1
Participant: Jake W
Registration type: general

List2:
Conference name: conference 1
Participant: John K
Registration type: plus
```

Do you know what can be the issue? Why is repeating the list 1 twice? If in this registration there are only 2 participants not 3.

Route:

```
Route::get('/registrationinfo/{regID}', [
    'uses' => 'RegistrationController@getRegistrationInfo',
    'as' => 'conferences.registrationInfo'
]);
```

Method:

```
   public function getRegistrationInfo($regID)
    {
        $registration = Registration::with('conference.registrationTypes.participants')
            ->find($regID);

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.registration', compact('registration'));

        return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');

    }
```

Blade file with pdf content:

```
@foreach($registration->conference->registrationTypes as $registrationType)
        @foreach($registrationType->participants as $participant)
            <li>
                <div class="wrapper">

                    <div>
                        <strong>Conference</strong>
                        <span>{{ $registrationType->conference->name}}</span>
                    </div>                      

                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <strong>Registration Type</strong><br>
                            <span>{{$registrationType->name}}</span><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <strong>Participante</strong><br>
                        <span>{{$participant->name}} {{$participant->surname}}</span><br>

                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <strong>Price of registration type</strong><br>
                        <span>{{number_format($registrationType->price, 2)}}€</span><br>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>

            <div class="breakNow"></div>

        @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's working exactly as it should, the problem being you aren't checking if a previous registration already exists. What's stopping a participant from registering multiple times? If the answer is nothing then the results are correct. Maybe what you're looking for is a unique validation rule to check if John or Jake has already registered? Or if multiple registrations is ok, then perhaps you want to use distinct and group by when querying to get only one registration per user?

Comment: Thanks, but a user can do multiple registrations in the same conference, but the pdf should only show the details of 1 specific registration ( the details of each specific registration).

Comment: You need to limit the number of participants returned in that case using `limit()` or `unique` when querying for `Registration::with()`. That will always return every participant for every registration unless further constraints are applied.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain better how to limit solves the issue? Becuase it should show all participants registered/ associated with the clicked registration. If there are for example 5 participants associated with the clicked registration it should show the 5 participants.

Comment: So, each registration is a different registration even if the same user does multiple registrations in the same conference, each registration of the user is a different registration and should have its specific details in the pdf when the "Download registration details"is clicked for each list item (for each registration).